# add media button is not working

Tags: images, media, buttons

Since last week I am experiencing that I am unable to add media to a portfolio item in the Parameters and Options field. When I click the button, nothing happens. When installing the theme on a sub-domain, the button works fine though.
Adding media using the button above the text-field works well, and inserting a featured-image is also possible.

**What i've tried so far without a positive result:**

1. test on Safari Chrome and Safari browsers
2. de-activate and check and activate all plugins
3. re-install Wordpress
4. re-install theme
5. delete cache & cookies
6. add "define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );" to
   wp-config.php
7. use browser console to look for JS errors